# In MSWord 2013 how do you word count table cells

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2013

I have a table in an MSWord 2013 document (docx) and In one of the columns of the table I want to insert the word count of an adjacent column. I'm okay doing a select the text and insert a field just haven't worked out how to do that. Inserting an excel style formula and copying it would be awesome but I wouldn't expect it to have a feature like that.

Comment: There isn't a field that would do this in Word, so you would have to use VBA to do the calculation (and the count would not be updated dynamically). What about the option of embedding an Excel table and using whatever Excel functions would do it?

Comment: It turns out that in order to achieve what I needed to achieve I am able to just use excel and put a word count formula in the adjacent cells. I'll leave this question here as it may help someone else.